# usage on c++ function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I'm a newbie to C++, learning pointer of function recently, a little confused by usage of pointer of function;

I practiced the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int subtraction(int a,int b){
    return a-b;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int (*minus)(int,int)=subtraction;
    cout<<minus(5,4);

    return 0;
}
```

it works well;
so,I try a little variation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int subtraction(int a,int b){
    return a-b;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int *minus(int,int)=subtraction;//only here different!
    cout<<minus(5,4);

    return 0;
}
```

I practiced it in Xcode on Mac,it give me Error:

> Illegal initializer (only variables can be initialized)

but I think compiler can recognized the two is same,why must have a pair of parenthesizes?

Comment: Same reason `int* minus(int,int)=subtraction;` doesn't work.

Comment: Do not use function pointers - better methods and more readable code. Consider the observer pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: @EdHeal: He's learning C++. It is useful to at least understand what it is.

Comment: @C.R. - The whole point of C++ is object oriented programming. Not functional

Comment: @EdHeal a) I would consider functor to be more directly comparable with function pointer and in this context a (command pattern)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern] would be closest for OOP and b) C++ is multi-paradigm language - including functional programming [(which is necessary exactly the same as using function pointers)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: Ups. There should be 'not neccesarly' instead of 'necessary'.

Comment: @EdHeal I never heard Bjarne Stroustrup say C++ is first and foremost an OOP language. The whole point of C++ is to be multiparadigm. In some cases functional programming is the best solution and it is available in C++, so it is good to try to learn how it works. Just look at the success of lambdas in C++11.

Comment: @MarcClaesen even more importantly, this isn't just what Bjarne says :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your original code

```
int (*minus)(int,int)=subtraction;
```

declares `minus` as a **function pointer** that takes parameter `int, int` and returns `int`.

In your second code

```
int *minus(int,int)=subtraction;
```

declares `minus` as a **function** that takes parameter `int, int` and returns a pointer `int *`.

You can use a function name(which is automatically converted to a function pointer) to initialize a function pointer, but you can't initialize a function.

Comment: IIRC the function name is not strictly a pointer as it has a function type but it is automatically converted to function pointer (similarly as arrays and pointers). Consider that `int (*minus)(int,int) = &subtraction;` is also valid.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka That's more precise, I'll edit my words, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The function call operator () has a higher precedence than the dereference operator *. So you must use parentheses to specify the correct order of evaluation.

```
int *minus(int, int)
```

means: First call a function named minus, *then* dereference the return value (int* in this case).

```
int (*minus)(int, int)
```

means: First dereference "minus", which returns a function, and *then* call that function.

Answer (score 3):

You have tagged your code `C++` and using `iostream` so I can safely assume you are looking for a C++ solution.

In such scenario, its best to use class template `std::function` instead of the  function pointer syntax that is prone to error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>


int subtraction(int a,int b){
    return a-b;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::function<int(int,int)> minus = subtraction;
    //int (*minus)(int,int)=subtraction;
    std::cout<<minus(5,4);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you would still want to continue with pointer to function, typedefs are recommended

```
#include <iostream>
int subtraction(int a,int b){
    return a-b;
}
typedef int (*MINUS)(int,int);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MINUS minus = subtraction;
    //int (*minus)(int,int)=subtraction;
    std::cout<<minus(5,4);

    return 0;
}
```

And finally, another widely used option is to use functors.

```
#include <iostream>
struct MINUS
{
    int operator()(int a,int b){
        return a-b;
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //int (*minus)(int,int)=subtraction;
    MINUS minus;
    std::cout<<minus(5,4);

    return 0;
}
```